# Appium NSPredicate Select A Single Item From a SUBQUERY

Tags: ios, appium, nspredicate

first day using NSPredicates with Appium.

Here is the issue.

I have 3 XCUIElementTypeTextField elements inside the view.

I can use Xpath to select using like this

> "(//XCUIElementTypeTextField)[1]"

then 2 and 3. However Xpath is slow and I'm now using NsPredicates when I need a more complex solution. While I know that I could search by other strategies does NSPredicate support selectors like the xpath one above?
Could I do:

> "SUBQUERY(*, $el, $el.type == 'XCUIElementTypeTextField')[0]"

this doesn't return a result however:

> "type =='XCUIElementTypeTextField'"

does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NSPredicate** is basically the way of defining logical conditions, **Xpath** is a language for searching XML.

I'm pretty sure you already checked, but maybe for others to get more knowledge about what you can do with NSPredicate check [official source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate)

Still more important to check what **works with Appium**: *NSPredicate-based locators* listed in **[XCUIModeTest.java](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/pagefactory_tests/XCUITModeTest.java)** and **[find_by_ios_predicate_tests.py](https://github.com/appium/python-client/blob/master/test/functional/ios/find_by_ios_predicate_tests.py)**

As a workaround for your case you can get a list of elements using your predicate and iterate through it later to get the needed one by index.

Comment: Thanks for the source code link. do you know thought is it possible to construct an array in NSPredicate and choose a single element based on index the way it is in Xpath? SUBQUERY is supposed to return an array and you can even get the count, but can you get an item by index?

Comment: looks like I can use this:    @iOSXCUITFindBy(iOSClassChain = "XCUIElementTypeWindow/*/XCUIElementTypeTextField[2]")